# Two unique marker symbols for one legend

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to add a "red filled square" symbol beside the "red filled circle" symbol under legend. How do I achieve this? I prefer to stick with pyplot rather than pylab.

Below is the code I've been using:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_axes([0.1,0.29,0.86,0.68])
plt.ylabel('Radial Velocity (km s$^{-1}$)')
plt.plot(time_model, rv_model_primary, 'k-', label = 'Primary')
plt.plot(time_model_sec, rv_model_secondary, 'k--', label = 'Secondary')
plt.plot(time_obs, rv_obs_primary, 'bo', label='XYZ')

plt.plot(time_obs_apg, rv_obs_primary_apg, 'ro', label='This Work')
plt.plot(time_obs_apg_sec, rv_obs_secondary_apg, 'rs')
plt.plot((0.0, 1.0),(0.0,0.0), 'k-.')
plt.legend(loc='upper left', numpoints=1)
```

Here's what I tried:

```
p1=plt.plot(time_model, rv_model_primary, 'k-')
p2=plt.plot(time_model_sec, rv_model_secondary, 'k--')
p3=plt.plot(time_obs, rv_obs_primary, 'bo')
p4=plt.plot(time_obs_apg, rv_obs_primary_apg, 'ro')
p5=plt.plot(time_obs_apg_sec, rv_obs_secondary_apg, 'rs')

plt.legend([p1,p2,p3,(p4,p5)],["Primary", "Secondary", "XYZ", "This Work"])
```

[image]

After making changes to the code using tcaswell's suggestions I get the following. The looks good but I would like to have just one symbol for blue while keeping the two for red. Currently there are two.

[image]

The final solution by adding numpoints=1 to the general legend() worked. Here's how I wanted it. Thanks tcaswell!

[image]

Comment: http://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide.html#legend-handler

Comment: yes, I looked at it before but could not get it to work. I got bunch of errors. Hence, I asked the question here. This is what I used: "plt.legend([p1a, (p1a, p1b)], ["Attr A", "Attr A+B"])" for my case.

Comment: nm, didn't read closely enough;)

Comment: It seems straight-forward. Why would it not work?

Comment: as a side note, you should make your example code copy-pastable.  No one wants to spend time making fake data to test your code;)

Comment: That's a good point. I will make sure to do so the next time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### solve exception issue

Suspect you need to do:

```
p1, = plt.plot(time_model, rv_model_primary, 'k-')
p2, = plt.plot(time_model_sec, rv_model_secondary, 'k--')
p3, = plt.plot(time_obs, rv_obs_primary, 'bo')
p4, = plt.plot(time_obs_apg, rv_obs_primary_apg, 'ro')
p5, = plt.plot(time_obs_apg_sec, rv_obs_secondary_apg, 'rs')
```

`plot` returns a list of `Line2D` objects (the extra `,` unpacks it) and I think that the expected types in  are getting mucked up.  This fixes your exceptions issue, but does not actually solve your problem.

### hacky solution

A some what hacky way to solve this is:

```
plt.legend([p1,p2,p3,(p5,p4)],["Primary", "Secondary", "XYZ", "This Work"],
           handler_map={p4:HandlerLine2D(numpoints=2), p5:HandlerLine2D(numpoints=1)})
```

which gives you three points, two of one and one of the other.

### cleaner solution

```
from matplotlib.legend_handler import HandlerLine2D

class HandlerXoffset(HandlerLine2D):
    def __init__(self, marker_pad=0.3, numpoints=1, x_offset=0,  **kw):
        HandlerLine2D.__init__(self, marker_pad=marker_pad, numpoints=numpoints, **kw)
        self._xoffset = x_offset
    def get_xdata(self, legend, xdescent, ydescent, width, height, fontsize):
        numpoints = self.get_numpoints(legend)

        if numpoints > 1:
            # we put some pad here to compensate the size of the
            # marker
            xdata = np.linspace(-xdescent + self._marker_pad * fontsize,
                                width - self._marker_pad * fontsize,
                                numpoints) - self._xoffset
            xdata_marker = xdata
        elif numpoints == 1:
            xdata = np.linspace(-xdescent, width, 2) - self._xoffset
            xdata_marker = [0.5 * width - 0.5 * xdescent - self._xoffset]

        print xdata, self._xoffset
        print xdata_marker

        return xdata, xdata_marker

time_model = time_model_sec = time_obs = time_obs_apg = time_obs_apg_sec = range(5)

rv_model_primary = np.random.rand(5)
rv_model_secondary = np.random.rand(5)
rv_obs_primary = np.random.rand(5)
rv_obs_primary_apg =  np.random.rand(5)
rv_obs_secondary_apg =  np.random.rand(5)

p1,=plt.plot(time_model, rv_model_primary, 'k-')
p2,=plt.plot(time_model_sec, rv_model_secondary, 'k--')
p3,=plt.plot(time_obs, rv_obs_primary, 'bo')
p4,=plt.plot(time_obs_apg, rv_obs_primary_apg, 'ro')
p5,=plt.plot(time_obs_apg_sec, rv_obs_secondary_apg, 'rs')

plt.legend([p1,p2,p3,(p5,p4)], 
           ["Primary", "Secondary", "XYZ", "This Work"],
            handler_map={p4:HandlerXoffset(x_offset=10),   
                         p5:HandlerXoffset(x_offset=-10)})
```

[gist](https://gist.github.com/tacaswell/6137157)

You will probably have to play with `x_offset` a bit to make it look right, and there is probably a better way to automatically figure out what it's value should be, but this should be enough to get you started.

[image]

Comment: yeah, at least the error went away. I am left with the following figure (see figure 2) above.

Comment: @aging_gorrila See the edit again.  Solution might be overkill, but it amuses me.

Comment: It's nearly there. Please see the updated figure above. When I use the numpoints in the legend now, I do not get one blue symbol and two red symbols. That's the ultimate objective. How would you add such? For example the following does not work: plt.legend([p1,p2,p3,(p5,p4)], 
           ["Primary", "Secondary", "XYZ", "This Work"],
            handler_map={p4:HandlerXoffset(x_offset=10, numpoints=1),   
                         p5:HandlerXoffset(x_offset=-10, numpoints=2)}, loc='upper left')

Comment: don't put code in the comment box, it is unreadable.  And I think just add `numpoints=1` as an argument to `legend`

Comment: Sweet! That worked. Check out the new figure. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Please suggest/edit the title of this question so that it is accessible for future queries. Thanks.